# How to use selenium web driver for all browser-chrome,safari,firefox,IE(JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium

Is there anyway, to detect client browser and use the webdriver accordingly in server side.
I need access the page in all browser.
Here is my code,

```
WebDriver webDriver=new FirefoxDriver();    

webDriver.get(url);
```

I need to open this,in all firefox,chrome,safari,IE.Please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you will run it will be opened :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. You're the tester, so it's up to **you** to write/follow your test plan and then write code/scripts to **explicitly** test each of the various browser/version combinations and their various nuances and subtleties (whilst trying to reuse as much logic as you can, minimise duplication etc.)

The nature of WebDriver is that you, the tester, are doing the driving - not the browser.

**Edit:** In answer to your specific question, yes, it's technically possible but you'd either need the site/webapp in question to know about your WebDriver server (total conflict of interests), or you'd need some kind of browser plugin to be a go-between.

Comment: Thanks,for your reply.I am trying to extract the complete web page source with the help of web driver & javascript executor by giving url. I used firefoxDriver and got output.But,now I am in a requirement to use all driver ,for clients compatibility.Please help,if you know.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to wrap all your code in some sort of for loop and repeat the task with each browser. Here is a code example:

```
WebDriver driver = null;
String[] browsers = {"chrome", "firefox", "ie", "edge", "opera"};
for (String browser : browsers) {
    switch(browser) {
        case "chrome":
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;

        case "firefox" = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;

        case "ie":
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            break;

        case "edge":
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
            break;

        case "opera":
            driver = new OperaDriver();
            break;
    }

    doWhatYouNeedWithDifferentBrowser(driver);
}
```

Some drivers need some extra configuration parameters and an external browser driver running.
You may have a look at [this example project on my GitHub](https://github.com/darugnaa/selenium-windows-quickstart) and a short [tutorial](http://darugnaa.github.io/2015/12/selenium-windows-quickstart/).

Comment: Thanks you,I have added this extra configuration parameter alone,            ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(); ,Got output : )

Comment: @user57 please accept my answer if it resolved your issue. Thank you.

Comment: yes,I have accepted,I just have reputation points:11 , After I reach 15 points ,it will show my vote for you..  : )